# double ranking in python after a groupby

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by

I have done a groupby which resulted in a dataframe similar to the below example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['A', 'A','A', 'B', 'B','B'], 'b': ['A1', 'A2','A3' ,'B1', 'B2','B3'], 'c': ['2','3','4','5','6','1'] })

>>> df
   a   b  c
0  A  A1  2
1  A  A2  3
2  A  A3  4
3  B  B1  5
4  B  B2  6
5  B  B3  1
```

desired output

```
>>> df
       a   b  c
    4  B  B2  6
    3  B  B1  5
    5  B  B3  1       
    2  A  A3  4
    1  A  A2  3
    0  A  A1  2
```

As you can see it is a double ranking based on column a then column b. We first start with the highest which is B and within B we also start with the highest which is B2.

how i can do that in python please

Comment: Whats happen if `2  A  A3  4` is changed to `2  A  A3  7` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can first find maxima in each group and sort your DF descending by this local maxima and column `c`:

```
In [49]: (df.assign(x=df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max'))
            .sort_values(['x','c'], ascending=[0,0])
            .drop('x',1))
Out[49]:
   a   b  c
4  B  B2  6
3  B  B1  5
5  B  B3  1
2  A  A3  4
1  A  A2  3
0  A  A1  2
```

Comment: Thank you MaxU. Whats the difference with previous answer? Are you just resetting the index? or doing something more than that?  by the way "sort_values" do not work for me

Comment: thanks for the updated answer. Even "assign" doesnt work for me. my firm has an old python version (which I am not allowed to upgrade)

Comment: what is your __pandas__ version?

Comment: >>> pd.__version__
'0.14.1'

Comment: @SBad, there is no need to touch the system Python - [you can install Anaconda distributive locally, create virtual environments and use those VirtualEnv's in your projects.](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) This is how i'm using it in my company - I have several VirtualEnv's with different modules and/or different module versions so they are totally independent from the system Python (usually it's Python 2.4 on old RedHat machines) and indepenedent from each other...

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
In [1072]: df.sort_values(by=['a', 'c'], ascending=[False, False])
Out[1072]:
   a   b  c
4  B  B2  6
3  B  B1  5
5  B  B3  1
2  A  A3  4
1  A  A2  3
0  A  A1  2
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  "sort_values" does not work for me so I have changed it with df.sort(['a', 'b'], ascending=[False, False])

Answer (score 2):

I think need first get `max` values by aggregating, then create ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) by ordering by `max` indices and last [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) working as you need:

```
c = df.groupby('a')['c'].max().sort_values(ascending=False)
print (c)
a
B    6
A    4
Name: c, dtype: object

df['a'] = pd.Categorical(df['a'], categories=c.index, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=['a', 'c'], ascending=[True, False])
print (df)
   a   b  c
4  B  B2  6
3  B  B1  5
5  B  B3  1
2  A  A3  4
1  A  A2  3
0  A  A1  2
```